# Ignoring God or lack of worship

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for the act of a believer temporarily ignoring, or failing to worship, (any) God?

For instance: "God is becoming vengeful due to your [lack of worship]."

Comment: `lack of faith`

Comment: "Lack of faith" or "little faith".

Comment: *Recidivism* in its sense of *returning to a state of sin*

Comment: Thanks @123 - I'm thinking of the situation where the believer still has faith, but their devotion / acts of worship have lapsed. (And, ideally, in a single word). Perhaps **infidelity**?

Comment: @CharlE Do you just google what people post and then use the first answer you come across, Recidivism has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @StevieP `Acts of defiance`, you are defying the laws of your god and they are vengeful ?

Comment: I find your lack of faith disturbing.

Comment: I originally considered apostasy and atheism but discounted them as they are by definition 'permanent' changes.

Comment: If it is for somebody devout that doesn't worship, the context changes and you'll need to think about why as it can change the word/phrases. Is it due to apathy, doubt, spite?

Comment: I'm thinking you could borrow a term such as "stiff necked" from the Bible.

Comment: how about `enlightenment`

Comment: Currently non-practicing, modify POS as needed

Comment: @HotLicks "Stiff-necked" means "prideful" or "obstinate" though; that is, in this case, too proud to lower oneself before God.  While this is certainly a complaint God levels at the Israelites many times in the Bible I think it's a little different from what the OP asked.

Comment: @Casey - Yeah, "stiff necked" is not dead-on, but I'm pretty sure there are several other similar terms in the Bible, and one might work.  (And one person I read comments from apparently (mis)interpreted "stiff necked" to mean "not bowing one's head in prayer", which *would* be dead-on.)

Comment: @Casey - (In any event, if you examine the Bible where "stiff-necked" is used the context is pretty much always "God is becoming vengeful due to your [lack of worship]", so you know that you're getting warm.)

Comment: @HotLicks Sure, but by that metric "whoredoms" works too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*God is becoming vengeful due to your lack of **piety**.*

This implies lack of actions, not lack of belief; the protagonist is not necessarily an atheist or an apostate.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piety) piety is

> noun - spiritual terminology, piety is a virtue that may include
>   religious devotion, spirituality, or a mixture of both.

and

> The word piety comes from the Latin word pietas, the noun form of the
>   adjective pius (which means "devout" or "dutiful"). Pietas in
>   traditional Latin usage expressed a complex, highly valued Roman
>   virtue; a man with pietas respected his responsibilities to gods,
>   country, parents, and kin.

Comment: To add to this answer, "impiety" would be a single word for the lack of piety.

Answer (score 10):

"God is becoming vengeful due to your backsliding".

> [backslide](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backslide): to lapse morally or in the practice of religion

Answer (score 9):

Here are three words:

1. Apostate, Apostacy.  One who abandons or renounces religious belief.
2. Recusant, Recusancy.  One who refuses to attend church services.
3. Reprobate, Reprobation.  Original Greek meaning, one who knew the truth in the past but has fully abandoned their faith, the final state of an Apostate.  See this post on ["What does it mean to have a reprobate mind?"](http://www.gotquestions.org/reprobate-mind.html) from GotQuestions.org.

Answer (score 7):

"Unfaithfulness"
"Repent from your acts of unfaithfulness"

[Faith is often used as if it simply meant belief, but it actually "implies unswerving adherence".](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faithful) 
Unfaithfulness (or the more Latin Infidelity) appropriately describes any relationship (spiritual, marital, etc.) that sees lapses of devotion, attention improperly directed elsewhere, or all forms of disloyalty.

Answer (score 5):

**irreverence**

would be one possibility.

> a. The fact or quality of being irreverent; absence or violation of reverence; disrespect to a person or thing held sacred or worthy of honour.

from the OED.

Answer (score 4):

There is an adjective for people who are a member of a faith but are not actively engaged with it:

> **non-practising**
>
> Brought up as a member of a particular religion but not following its rules and practices
> *a non-practising Catholic*

[Source: Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/non-practising)

I didn't see a source on a noun form that retains the religious connection, but you could write your sentence as

> God is becoming vengeful due to your nonpractising nature.